# Como inserir uma letra entre duas palavras numa string php?

Tags: php

Tenho de inserir uma monossílabo entre duas palavras dentro de uma string em PHP, como nos exemplos abaixo:

```
// entrada
string=> vinte cinco 
// saída
string=> vinte e cinco
```

---

```
// entrada
string=> vinte cinco mil 
// saída
string=> vinte e cinco  mil
```

---

```
// entrada
string=> vinte cinco reais e vinte cinco centavos
// saída 
string=> vinte e cinco reais e vinte e cinco centavos
```

Comment: E se a string for `aaa bbb ccc` vai dois `e`? ta meio vago o critério.

Comment: Sempre terá este tamanho fixo `aaa  aaa`?

Comment: sim pode acontecer isso: aaa bbb ccc => aaa e bbb e ccc

Comment: o tamanho vai ater 6 casas decimais

Comment: Isso resolve? `$str = 'aaa bbb ccc '; echo str_replace(' ', ' e ', $str);`

Comment: perfeito...resposta certa

Comment: pode responder a pergunta ..para vc ganhar seus pontos!!

Comment: Certeza? vai retornar `vinte E cinco E reais`

Comment: aqui esta funcionando perfeitamente

Comment: Está parecendo um caso de [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878). Não seria melhor você colocar na pergunta qual é o problema que precisa resolver?

Comment: Como notado pelo Anderson, você está querendo abrir o coco ou quer saber como repor a peneira de modo automático após o disparo do tanque de guerra?

Comment: A solução do @rray para `vinte cinco mil` daria ruim `vinte e cinco e mil` e para `vinte cinco reais e vinte cinco centavos` daria `vinte e cinco e reais e e e vinte e cinco e centavos`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para números, "e" é usado no meio destes 5 casos:

1. Entre dezenas e unidades, de 21 a 99.
2. Entre centenas e dezenas ou unidades, de 101 a 999.
3. Entre milhares e dezenas ou unidades
   (Exemplos: *dois mil e trinta*, *cinco mil e oito*).
4. Entre milhares e centenas, somente se não houver dezenas ou unidades
   (Exemplo: *oito mil e quatrocentos*).
5. Entre milhões e dezenas ou unidades
   (Exemplo: *dois milhões e trinta e um*).

Podemos usar uma expressão regular para encontrar a posição onde deve haver um "e". <kbd>[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yna3A6/1)</kbd>

```
/

# Definição de ordens
(?(DEFINE)(?P<unidades>            um|dois|tr[eê]s|quatro|cinco|meia|se(?:is|te)|oito|nove                        ))
(?(DEFINE)(?P<dezenas_dez>         d(?:ez(?:e(?:nove|sse(?:is|te))|oito)?|oze)|onze|treze|catorze|quinze          ))
(?(DEFINE)(?P<dezenas_exceto_dez>  vinte|trinta|(?:quar|cinqu|se(?:ss|t)|oit|nov)enta                             ))
(?(DEFINE)(?P<dezenas>             (?P>dezenas_dez)|(?P>dezenas_exceto_dez)                                       ))
(?(DEFINE)(?P<dezenas_ou_unidades> (?P>dezenas)|(?P>unidades)                                                     ))
(?(DEFINE)(?P<centenas>            ce(?:m|ntos?)|(?:qu(?:atroc|inh)|(?:du|tre|se(?:is|te)|oito|nove)[cz])entos?   ))
(?(DEFINE)(?P<mil>                 mil                                                                            ))
(?(DEFINE)(?P<milhoes>             (?:(?:[mb]|tr)i|qu(?:atri|inqua))lh(?:[aã]o|[oõ]es)                            ))
(?(DEFINE)(?P<s>                   [ ]+                                                                           ))
(?(DEFINE)(?P<e>                   e(?P>s)                                                                        ))


#Regras
\b(?:

    #1. Entre dezenas>=20 e unidades
    (?P>dezenas_exceto_dez)(?P>s)(?=(?P>unidades)\b)
|
    #2. Entre centenas e dezenas ou unidades
    (?P>centenas)(?P>s)(?=(?P>dezenas_ou_unidades)\b)
|
    #3-4. Entre milhares...
    (?P>mil)(?P>s)(?=
        (?:
            #3. ... e dezenas ou unidades
            (?P>dezenas_ou_unidades)
        |
            #4. ... e centenas, somente se não houver dezenas ou unidades
            (?P>centenas)(?!(?P>s)(?P>e)?(?P>dezenas_ou_unidades)\b)
        )
        \b
    )
|
    #5. Entre milhões e dezenas ou unidades (que não sejam unidades ou dezenas de milhões ou unidades ou dezenas de milhares)
    (?P>milhoes)(?P>s)(?=
        (?P>dezenas_ou_unidades)(?!(?P>s)(?P>e)?(?:(?P>unidades)(?P>s)(?P>e)?)?(?:(?P>milhoes)|(?P>mil))\b)\b

    )

)
\b

#Reset
\K

/iux
```

Ou, em uma única linha, sem comentários:

```
/(?(DEFINE)(?P<unidades>um|dois|tr[eê]s|quatro|cinco|meia|se(?:is|te)|oito|nove))(?(DEFINE)(?P<dezenas_dez>d(?:ez(?:e(?:nove|sse(?:is|te))|oito)?|oze)|onze|treze|catorze|quinze))(?(DEFINE)(?P<dezenas_exceto_dez>vinte|trinta|(?:quar|cinqu|se(?:ss|t)|oit|nov)enta))(?(DEFINE)(?P<dezenas>(?P>dezenas_dez)|(?P>dezenas_exceto_dez)))(?(DEFINE)(?P<dezenas_ou_unidades>(?P>dezenas)|(?P>unidades)))(?(DEFINE)(?P<centenas>ce(?:m|ntos?)|(?:qu(?:atroc|inh)|(?:du|tre|se(?:is|te)|oito|nove)[cz])entos?))(?(DEFINE)(?P<mil>mil))(?(DEFINE)(?P<milhoes>(?:(?:[mb]|tr)i|qu(?:atri|inqua))lh(?:[aã]o|[oõ]es)))(?(DEFINE)(?P<s> +))(?(DEFINE)(?P<e>e(?P>s)))\b(?:(?P>dezenas_exceto_dez)(?P>s)(?=(?P>unidades)\b)|(?P>centenas)(?P>s)(?=(?P>dezenas_ou_unidades)\b)|(?P>mil)(?P>s)(?=(?:(?P>dezenas_ou_unidades)|(?P>centenas)(?!(?P>s)(?P>e)?(?P>dezenas_ou_unidades)\b))\b)|(?P>milhoes)(?P>s)(?=(?P>dezenas_ou_unidades)(?!(?P>s)(?P>e)?(?:(?P>unidades)(?P>s)(?P>e)?)?(?:(?P>milhoes)|(?P>mil))\b)\b))\b\K/iux
```

Substituindo pelo texto: `'e '`.

> Eu estabeleci o limite para quinqualhão (10^18). Pode completá-lo, ou usar:
>
> ```
> (?(DEFINE)(?P<milhoes>\w+lh(?:[aã]o|[oõ]es)))
> ```
>
> como caso generalizado.

---

#### Código:

```
<?php    // https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257031/53463

$re = '/
        # Definição de ordens
        (?(DEFINE)(?P<unidades>            um|dois|tr[eê]s|quatro|cinco|meia|se(?:is|te)|oito|nove                        ))
        (?(DEFINE)(?P<dezenas_dez>         d(?:ez(?:e(?:nove|sse(?:is|te))|oito)?|oze)|onze|treze|catorze|quinze          ))
        (?(DEFINE)(?P<dezenas_exceto_dez>  vinte|trinta|(?:quar|cinqu|se(?:ss|t)|oit|nov)enta                             ))
        (?(DEFINE)(?P<dezenas>             (?P>dezenas_dez)|(?P>dezenas_exceto_dez)                                       ))
        (?(DEFINE)(?P<dezenas_ou_unidades> (?P>dezenas)|(?P>unidades)                                                     ))
        (?(DEFINE)(?P<centenas>            ce(?:m|ntos?)|(?:qu(?:atroc|inh)|(?:du|tre|se(?:is|te)|oito|nove)[cz])entos?   ))
        (?(DEFINE)(?P<mil>                 mil                                                                            ))
        (?(DEFINE)(?P<milhoes>             (?:(?:[mb]|tr)i|qu(?:atri|inqua))lh(?:[aã]o|[oõ]es)                            ))
        (?(DEFINE)(?P<s>                   [ ]+                                                                           ))
        (?(DEFINE)(?P<e>                   e(?P>s)                                                                        ))


        #Regras
        \b(?:

            #1. Entre dezenas>=20 e unidades
            (?P>dezenas_exceto_dez)(?P>s)(?=(?P>unidades)\b)
        |
            #2. Entre centenas e dezenas ou unidades
            (?P>centenas)(?P>s)(?=(?P>dezenas_ou_unidades)\b)
        |
            #3-4. Entre milhares...
            (?P>mil)(?P>s)(?=
                (?:
                    #3. ... e dezenas ou unidades
                    (?P>dezenas_ou_unidades)
                |
                    #4. ... e centenas, somente se não houver dezenas ou unidades
                    (?P>centenas)(?!(?P>s)(?P>e)?(?P>dezenas_ou_unidades)\b)
                )
                \b
            )
        |
            #5. Entre milhões e dezenas ou unidades (que não sejam unidades ou dezenas de milhões ou unidades ou dezenas de milhares)
            (?P>milhoes)(?P>s)(?=
                (?P>dezenas_ou_unidades)(?!(?P>s)(?P>e)?(?:(?P>unidades)(?P>s)(?P>e)?)?(?:(?P>milhoes)|(?P>mil))\b)\b

            )

        )
        \b

        #Reset
        \K

    /iux';

$subst = 'e ';


//Exemplos     
$teste = [
            'vinte cinco',
            'vinte cinco mil',
            'vinte cinco reais',
            'vinte cinco reais e vinte cinco centavos',
            'aaa bbb ccc',
            'dois mil trezentos',
            'dois mil trezentos quarenta cinco',
            'dois milhões trinta um',
            'dois milhões trinta um mil',
            'dois milhões trinta mil',
            'dois milhões trinta um',
            'cento vinte três milhões quatrocentos cinquenta seis mil setecentos oitenta nove'
        ];

//Substituir
$resultado = preg_replace($re, $subst, $teste);


//Mostrar em uma única matriz
$resultado_final = array_combine( $teste, $resultado);
var_export($resultado_final);
```

Resultado:

```
array (
  'vinte cinco' => 'vinte e cinco',
  'vinte cinco mil' => 'vinte e cinco mil',
  'vinte cinco reais' => 'vinte e cinco reais',
  'vinte cinco reais e vinte cinco centavos' => 'vinte e cinco reais e vinte e cinco centavos',
  'aaa bbb ccc' => 'aaa bbb ccc',
  'dois mil trezentos' => 'dois mil e trezentos',
  'dois mil trezentos quarenta cinco' => 'dois mil trezentos e quarenta e cinco',
  'dois milhões trinta um' => 'dois milhões e trinta e um',
  'dois milhões trinta um mil' => 'dois milhões trinta e um mil',
  'dois milhões trinta mil' => 'dois milhões trinta mil',
  'cento vinte três milhões quatrocentos cinquenta seis mil setecentos oitenta nove' => 'cento e vinte e três milhões quatrocentos e cinquenta e seis mil setecentos e oitenta e nove',
)
```

<kbd>[ideone.com](https://ideone.com/RHCCVg)</kbd>

Comment: sextilhão, septilhão, octilhão, nonilhão, decilhão, ........, tredecilhão etc.... ? Tá incompleto :)

Comment: Nada disso q vc tá pensando, só quis brincar com vc, achei até demasiado chegar a casa dos milhões. O código eu entendi, senão não partiria da casa dos sextilhões na brincadeira

Comment: Valeu @Leo. Adicionei uma nota sobre o limite.

Comment: Essa cifra só pra quem mora em Brasilia, hehehe, +1 dado

Comment: O código esta completo. Quase um TCC...

Answer (score 2):

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/AWIKJQ)

```
$result="";

$str = 'vinte cinco reais e vinte cinco centavos'; 

/*****Opcional, para prevenir entradas adversas****/
//Primeiro usa o trim() para limpar os espaços do início e do final da string.
//preg_replace() para remover os espaços duplicados.
//O caracter de escape \s significa "qualquer espaço em branco".
//A notação (?=) é usada para realizar pesquisa adiante. Na prática ele significa "qualquer espaço que é seguido por outro espaço". Isso remove os duplicados, deixando apenas um espaço em branco.
$str=trim(preg_replace('/\s(?=\s)/', '', $str));
/*****fim, para prevenir entradas adversas****/

//substitue todos os caracteres " e " por " " na string
$str = str_replace(" e ", " ", $str);

//cria array
$a = explode(" ",$str);

//itera o array e concatena " e " quando necessário
for($i=0; $i < count($a); $i++){

      //interrompe o laço for para evitar o erro Notice: Undefined offset para "$a[$i+1]" caso fosse realizado a ultima iteraçao
      if($i == count($a)-1){
        $result = $result . $a[$i];
        break;
      }

      //concatena  " e " quando necessário
      if (($a[$i+1]=="reais")||($a[$i+1]=="mil")||($a[$i+1]=="centavos")){
        $result = $result . $a[$i] . " ";
      }else{
        $result = $result . $a[$i] . " e ";
      }

}

echo $result;
```

> para responder a pergunta do @R.Santos `

mil cento dez? Como ficaria?`

> basta incluir mais essa condição `($a[$i+1]=="cento")` nessa linha

```
if (($a[$i+1]=="reais")||($a[$i+1]=="mil")||($a[$i+1]=="centavos")){
```

> ficando então assim

```
if (($a[$i+1]=="reais")||($a[$i+1]=="mil")||($a[$i+1]=="centavos")||($a[$i+1]=="cento")){
```

[**resultado - ideone**](https://ideone.com/NHZxB9)

Comment: mil cento dez? Como ficaria?

Comment: não testei pq não foi aventada essa hipotese mas acho que ficaria `mil e cento e dez`

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257099/erro-na-sa%C3%ADda-da-data-por-extenso. Acredito que seja isso que ele queira, na verdade nem tem `cento` na lista dele somente `cem` o que acaba sendo um erro da parte dele. mas acredito que será necessário comportar essa opção pelo menos `1210`

Comment: pois é, trezentos, quatrocentos etcc  milhão bilhão etccc dai fica ruim. Mas nada que com um pouco mais de trabalho se chegue ao desejado

Comment: Pois é, `bilhões` já é outra opção que não tem também somente `milhões`

Comment: @R.Santos,  para responder sua `mil cento dez? Como ficaria?`  veja https://ideone.com/NHZxB9

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69062/discussion-between-r-santos-and-leo-caracciolo).